# Poor time utilization shown by vtune but the issue is unknown

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel, intel-vtune

Analyzing a packet processing application with Intel Vtune.

Poor time utilization in just this instruction

```
add $0x100, %r8 (7%)
```

Poor time utilization in a single if check

```
if(unlikely(VALUE == some_value)
```

This some_value is uint16_t and is passed as (int*)&some_value and is further accessed as (uint8_t*)some_value if that helps.

maps to the following

```
movzxw 0x3e(%rsp),%eax
test %ax,%ax ---- Leads in poor time utilization
jz Block x
```

Poor time utilization in a function pushing variables to stack
while others push the same variables and take up much less time

```
pushq %r15
pushq %r14
pushq %r13
pushq %r12
pushq %rbp
pushq %rbx 
sub $0x48, %rsp
movq %rsi, 0x18(%rsp)
```

Shows the same issue in memory access analysis, branch misprediction analysis etc. Don't understand how to overcome this problem

Comment: it helps if you show the data and point out why you think it's poor time utilization.

Comment: That casting looks pretty dodgy to me, not just from a performance perspective.

Comment: It could be an attempt to make the compiler keep this variable in memory (a little like trying to use volatile to do that, which is often done wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Intel performance counters aren't cycle-accurate.  Sometimes a nearby instruction gets the cycle counts for stalls in a different instruction.  (nearby = 1 or 2 instructions away).

Unless there's some really weird decode bottleneck, there's no way `add $0x100, %r8` is actually taking a lot of time relative to other nearby instructions.  Unless it's getting dinged for needing the value of `%r8` before it's ready, maybe.  IDK if the perf counters work that way.

The `test / jz` pair macro-fuses into a single uop.  The time there is not from the `test`, but probably from the branch.  Is it mispredicting a lot?

Slow pushing variables: Is that function recursive?  Or at the end of a long call chain?  If it's pushing values into a cacheline (or worse, page) of memory that hasn't been touched for a while, it won't be in L1 cache and will be slow to access.

In all the cases, more context is needed to say anything definite.  One instruction by itself is pretty much useless for performance analysis.